# C# watcher on file rename: Windows sends Renamed, but OS X/Mono sends Changed+Created+Deleted

Tags: c#, macos, mono, filesystemwatcher, file-rename

*(OS X 10.9.5, Mono 3.10.0, Xamarin Studio 5.5.4build15)*

I have created this watcher which inherits from [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
#if __MonoCS__
    // http://stackoverflow.com/q/16859372
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MONO_MANAGED_WATCHER", "enabled");
#endif

Path = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(folder);
IncludeSubdirectories = true;
Filter = "*";
InternalBufferSize = 4 * 1024 * 16;
NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Size |
           NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

Error += new ErrorEventHandler(OnError);
Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);
Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnDeleted);
Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);
```

On both Windows and OS X, I tried renaming `file.txt` to `file2.txt`.

On **Windows** it works great: I receive one Renamed (name=file2.txt oldName=file.txt).

On **Mono/OS X** I just receive:

1. Changed file.txt
2. Created file2.txt
3. Deleted file.txt

Am I doing something wrong?
Is there any trick to make Mono send a RenamedEvent?
Or a known workaround to make renames easier to handle as a single event?

Comment: you should 1. state what mono version you're using, and 2. test with mono master branch, because many changes have landed recently on this front which could maybe fix this to make it work like in Windows

Comment: @knocte: 1. Done, thanks! 2. In progress :-)